# Datawig library imputes some of the columns while leaving some unimputed

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, imputation

I have been trying to impute missing values in my dataset using datawig library. However when I use datawig library to impute the missing values in my dataset. It imputes each and every other column while leaving behind two columns. Both of the columns are of dtype: object. However, it imputes other object columns. Here is the visualization of my dataset:

```
df.tail(155)
```

[image]

The code to impute the missing values is as follows:

```
import datawig
df = datawig.SimpleImputer.complete(df)
```

These are the missing values left behind:

```
df.isnull().sum()
PassengerId       0
HomePlanet        0
CryoSleep         0
Cabin           199
Destination       0
Age               0
VIP               0
RoomService       0
FoodCourt         0
ShoppingMall      0
Spa               0
VRDeck            0
Name            200
Transported       0
dtype: int64
```

The missing values for the column named Cabin and Name were left and were not imputed for I do not know what reason. Also before applying datawig imputation the number of missing values in Name and Cabin column were the same.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of the package, but those two columns are maybe too close to unique to make imputing make sense?

Comment: what do you mean by too close to unique? Can you please elaborate?